# Orchard CMS 1.6 placement.info Order not working

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I've just migrated a site to 1.6 - form 1.5, and I'm experiencing issues with the placement.info file in my theme,

I have the following placement

```
<Match DisplayType="Detail">
    <Place Parts_Title="/BeforeMain:1.5"/>
</Match>
```

I aslo have a Bred crumb menu widget placed in Before main with a placement setting of 5

No matter what I do to the numeric placement values, the Title always appears before the bread crumbs.

I'm also experiencing other issues with the theme placement.info file anybody else getting this. any ideas ?

This works in 1.5

**Update** - see comments

[image]

[image]

**Update 2**

```
<Match ContentType="AlternateIndexPage">
    <Place Parts_Introduction="/BeforeMain:4"/>
    <Place Parts_Title="/BeforeMain:3"/>
    <Place Fields_Input__AltenateIndexPage_VideoUrl="/BeforeMain:2"/>
<Math>
```

No matter what numbers / order I include in the palcement.info file the Video always apear first the title second and the intro third. If I use '-' the item disappear so I know the placement file is working - a bit

Comment: Where is this placement file? Can you please show the placement for the breadcrumb?
If this really works in 1.5 and not 1.6, then it's a regression and you should file a bug.

Comment: The placement.info is under a custom theme, the Breadcrumbs are added as a widget on the not the Homepage layer, I'll try and add picture to the question...

Comment: Ah, I see. I'll answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Widget position and placement are not the same thing unfortunately. I'm suspecting that if this worked in 1.5 it was a coincidence. Please file a bug so that this can be made to work in a future version.

A (not ideal) workaround would be to split that zone in two and send the widget to one, and the title to the other.

Comment: Just wanted to check this out a bit further, the Placement.info file dosent seem to work at all in term of the numbers I have 3 items and they always display in the same order no matter what the order of the placment.info file is. will file a bug

Comment: Wasn't sure how to add Zones, turns out it's very easy, in case anyone else was wondering http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/databases/content-management-systems/9781449339746/layouts/id2788233